# expectation of log(1-x^a) if x is a beta random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, integration, expectation

How can I compute $\mathbb{E}_{q}\Big[\log (1-x^a)\Big]$ when the distribution of $q$ is given as $q(x)\sim\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can do nothing with this expectation in general:

[image]

So, it is highly unlikely that this expectation can be expressed in terms of elementary, or even special, functions.

However, we have this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Also, writing $\ln(1-x^a)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{ak}}k$, we see that the expectation in question is
$$-\frac{\Gamma (\alpha+\beta )}
{\Gamma (\alpha)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma (a k+\alpha )}{k\,\Gamma (a k+\alpha +\beta )}.$$
It is highly unlikely as well that the latter sum can be expressed in terms of elementary, or even special, functions:

[image]

---

Of course, one can compute this expectation numerically with any degree of accuracy. E.g., we have this:

[image]

Comment: @losifPinelis What about some sort of Taylor expansion?

Comment: @Dalek : I have added the use of a Taylor expansion.

Comment: @Dalek : Do you have a further response to this answer?

Comment: When $a = 1$, how does $\mathbb{E}[log (1 - x)]$ become that difference of polygamma functions?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer : This was done by Mathematica, not me. However, this can be done by hand too, by differentiating (with respect to the second argument) both the defining expression for the beta function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and its expression in terms of the gamma function.